# How to wait for a JFrame thread to finish from inside a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, swing, javafx

I'm trying to create a JFrame window from inside a JavaFX application. I'm using Oracle Java 8 and I'm able to do what I need in Linux, Windows but not in Mac OS. It seems like a JVM implementation issue. Here are my requirements:

- I need to call a library method which creates a game window(an extended class from JFrame). I need to be able to use keyboard in game.
- I can access the source code of the library but I don't have any intention to change the source code of the library
- I need to process game information after the game finished, so my main thread needs to wait until the game finishes

I created sample application below. Application works fine under Linux and Windows, but in Mac OS when I try to wait for the JFrame thread to finish app freezes and JFrame is not shown. SwingUtilities.invokeLater doesn't freeze but it doesn't wait for JFrame thread to finish. Since I need to wait for the JFrame thread invokeLater is not an option for me.

JFrameCreator.java

```
public class JFrameCreator implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Creating JFrame");
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            frame.getContentPane().getGraphics().drawOval(150-i/2,150-i/2,i,i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="51.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createJFrame" text="New JFrame" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="cbThread" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Thread">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="tg" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton fx:id="cbInvokeWait" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="invokeAndWait" toggleGroup="$tg" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="cbInvokeLater" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="invokeLater" toggleGroup="$tg" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML RadioButton cbThread;
    @FXML RadioButton cbInvokeWait;
    @FXML RadioButton cbInvokeLater;

    public void createJFrame(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Runnable r=new JFrameCreator();
        try {
            if (cbThread.isSelected()) {
                Thread t=new Thread(new JFrameCreator());
                t.start();
                t.join();
            }
            else if(cbInvokeWait.isSelected())
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
            else
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
        }
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I also tried a while loop with Thread.isAlive() method but that also behaves like Thread.join(). How can I achieve my requirements?

Comment: FYI: You `for-loop` where you "paint" stuff is a really bad idea.

Comment: Why not use a "producer/consumer" pattern - where, when the "swing" portion has completed it's job, it notifies the "JavaFX" portion via a callback

Comment: @MadProgrammer that for loop might be a bad practice, but I put that to create some delay in worker. For producer/consumer please see my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50788497/9893994) to Slaw's post

Comment: Apart from the `Thread`, using `getGraphics` is a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the synchronization classes such as [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Pass it to your `Runnable` and call `latch.countDown()` at the end of the `run()` method. Meanwhile, your JavaFX thread would be paused on `latch.await()`. This will freeze the JavaFX UI, however, so this might not be what you want.

Another option would be to use a callback. Something like:

```
public class JFrameCreator implements Runnable {

    private final Runnable onFinished;

    public JFrameCreator(Runnable onFinished) {
        this.onFinished = onFinished;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your work...
        Platform.runLater(onFinished); // to communicate to JavaFX Application
                                       // Thread that JFrameCreator is complete
    }

}
```

This second option won't cause the JavaFX thread to *wait* but it does allow you to react at the appropriate time. You could change the type of `onFinished` to whatever you need; such as a `Consumer` if you want to pass the callback some object.

Comment: CountDownLatch behaves same as Thread.join(). I need to block JavaFX application. If I don't, user can create many instances of game(s) since JavaFX application will be available for JavaFX component events.

Comment: @caki If the game instance is launched via a UI element, such as a `Button`, simply disable the `Button` when an instance is launched. Then, using the callback option, re-enable the `Button` in the callback so another instance may be launched. To make it even safer, in the action handler of the `Button` check if an instance is already running and, if there is one, don't launch another one.

Comment: I tried your workaround on main project. It works and solved my problem. I also would like to know why trying to join other thread freezes on Mac OS.